# SQL : don't show columns with non data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL output like this

```
t1.column1   t1.column2   t2.column3  t2.column4 ...

#1blabla     blabla       blabla      blabla ..
#2blabla     blabla                   blabla ..
```

I would like to write a SQL statement that only shows rows which actually have data in it from column3.

In this case, row #2 should not be shown.

Any ideas?

I got this so far:

```
select *
from
    table1 t1, table2 t2
where
    t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: AND NOT t2.column3 IS NULL

Comment: IS NOT NULL you mean @JeremyC.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @sqluser No, i always put my not statement on the start of the clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IS NOT NULL`!

```
select *
from table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
where t2.column3 IS NOT NULL;
```

Re-wrote with modern JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It seems u can use:

```
select *
from
table1 t1,
table2 t2
where
t1.id = t2.id and t2.colum3 is not null
```